# Linux - Import SQL File Into Non-Existant Database

Tags: mysql, linux

Normally I have database already created.  So this command line works find:

> mysql -h  -u  -p [databaseName] < dump.sql

I have an `import.sql` file that has a top query that creates the database, if it doesn't already exist.

Is there a way to import the sql file, but without needing to select a pre-existing database?

Answer (score 2):

Invoke the commandline without specifying the database

```
mysql -h -u -p < dump.sql
```

inside dump.sql, after you create the database add

```
USE databasename;
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating the dump file using `mysqldump` you can use the switch `--add-drop-database`. This will include a statement to drop the database first. So in the subsequent statement, a fresh database will be created since no database with the given name exists

See [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for more